# bluetoothctl devices fails in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 and having trouble with bluetooth. When I issue the command **bluetooth devices**,I get

```
$ bluetoothctl devices
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot
be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
```

This problem has been noted before, but none of the solutions I've seen online work for me.
For example:

```
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ export
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ bluetoothctl devices ERROR: ld.so:
object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD
cannot be preloaded (wrong EL
```

Output requested by N0rbert:

```
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ arch
x86_64
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ uname -a
Linux HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx 5.4.0-70-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 19 13:29:52 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0: setuid ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=63e14ded4f568438f8b629bea2461c117db8a5d0, stripped
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ apt-cache policy libgtk3-nocsd0
libgtk3-nocsd0:
  Installed: 3-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 3-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Alas:

```
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtk3-nocsd0
[sudo] password for pwa: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 82 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libgtk3-nocsd0 amd64 3-1ubuntu1 [13.8 kB]
Fetched 13.8 kB in 0s (129 kB/s)          
(Reading database ... 347628 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgtk3-nocsd0_3-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgtk3-nocsd0:amd64 (3-1ubuntu1) over (3-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgtk3-nocsd0:amd64 (3-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ bluetoothctl devices
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ arch
x86_64
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ uname -a
Linux HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx 5.4.0-70-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 19 13:29:52 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0: setuid ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=63e14ded4f568438f8b629bea2461c117db8a5d0, stripped
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ apt-cache policy libgtk3-nocsd0
libgtk3-nocsd0:
  Installed: 3-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 3-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ bluetoothctl devices
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
```

```
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtk3-nocsd0
[sudo] password for pwa: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 82 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libgtk3-nocsd0 amd64 3-1ubuntu1 [13.8 kB]
Fetched 13.8 kB in 0s (129 kB/s)          
(Reading database ... 347628 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgtk3-nocsd0_3-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgtk3-nocsd0:amd64 (3-1ubuntu1) over (3-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgtk3-nocsd0:amd64 (3-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ bluetoothctl devices
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ arch
x86_64
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ uname -a
Linux HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx 5.4.0-70-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 19 13:29:52 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0: setuid ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=63e14ded4f568438f8b629bea2461c117db8a5d0, stripped
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ apt-cache policy libgtk3-nocsd0
libgtk3-nocsd0:
  Installed: 3-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 3-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ bluetoothctl devices
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
```

Comment: Please add the output of `arch`, `uname -a`, `file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0`, `apt-cache policy libgtk3-nocsd0` to the question by editing it.

Comment: Try to reinstall the problematic package by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtk3-nocsd0` .

Comment: Still no luck after reinstalling libgtk3-nocsd0

Comment: Here's an even simpler manifestation of the bug: just call  bluetoothctl with no parameters.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is a bug in bluez. I've reported it (I think) to ubuntubug, but I couldn't figure out whether my report actually gave someone enough information to see what the problem is.

Comment: I'm able to discover all my devices if I call bluetoothctl as superuser. but I still cannot connect to any of them.

Comment: There are  probably more than ten threads in various places about this problem.  Some say they've fixed it but for others the recommended solution doesn't work. Very frustrating.  I once got the connection but wasn't t able to use it.  I think the reason for all the discrepancies are that the solution is environment-sensitive.  The one thing that seems to be pretty certain is that if you encounter a problem in loading bluetoothctl, you can fix it by running bluetoothctl as root (with sudo).

Comment: `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` please. any programs on your system from not ubuntu sources?

Answer (score 1):

This very specific aspect of the bluetooth problems can be cured by running bluetoothctl as root (with sudo). Unfortunately that's not enough to actually get bluetooth working. And if you can get your bluetooth device to connect (not just pair), you've probably gotten more than half way to a solution).